# Read and copy text files by date into active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, file-io

I'm trying to create a macro that reads each *.txt file from a folder, and if the modification date matches the current one, copy the contents into a worksheet of the *.xls file. I've been checking a lot of the codes you have been sharing here, but I just can't make it work.

When debbuging, at the 8th line, I get an error:

> 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub GetSAPfiles()
    Dim Cont As Integer
    Dim RootDir As String
    RootDir = "\HOME\SAP\dir\"
    SAPfile = Dir(RootDir)
    Set SAPfile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SF = SAPfile.GetFile(RootDir + SAPfile)

    Do While SAPfile <> ""
        Dim ObjDate, CurrDate
        CurrDate = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
        ObjDate = Format(file.DateLastModified, "MM/DD/YYYY")

        If CurrDate = ObjDate Then
            Cont = Cont + 1
            Dim TxtFl, Txt
            Set TxtFl = SAPfile.OpenTextFile(RootDir + SAPfile)
            Txt = TxtFl.ReadLine
            ActiveSheet.Cells(Cont, "A").Value = Txt
            ArchTxt.Close
        End If
        SAPfile = Dir(RootDir)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Make both dates integers: `CurrDate = Format(INT(Now()), "MM/DD/YYYY")` and `ObjDate = Format(INT(CDATE(file.DateLastModified)), "MM/DD/YYYY")`

Comment: You have `SAPfile` assigned to a string, and then to an FSO object? The `Do While` statement is invalid, because at this point `SAPfile` is actually the FileSystemObject which cannot be evaluated against a null string ("")

Comment: Like I said, I just started creating macros, had no idea on how to work with objects here, so I had to ask for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead, use the command prompt to get an array of files and loop through them using the FSO to check the modified date and read the text into the next blank cell in column A:

```
Sub SO()

   RootDir$ = "\HOME\SAP\dir\"

   For Each x In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR " & RootDir & "*.* /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
       With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
           If DateValue(.GetFile(RootDir & x).DateLastModified) = Date Then _
                 Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .OpenTextFile(RootDir & x, 1).ReadAll
       End With
   Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Well this was great. It worked wonderfully, but more than that, it is faster than the way I expected (There's more than 6k files in the folder). Thanks a lot man.